# How can I place an image back in the same S3 bucket after running AWS Lambda function?

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I currently have two buckets in S3 - let's call them `photos` and `photos-thumbnails`. Right now, when a user uploads an image from our iOS app, we directly upload that photo to the `photos` bucket, which triggers a lambda function that resizes the photo into a thumbnail and uploads the thumbnail into the `photos-thumbnails` bucket.

I now want to include some image compression for the images in the `photos` bucket before a thumbnail is created in the original bucket (`photos`). However, if I set the compression lambda function to be triggered whenever an object is created in the `photos` bucket, it will wind up in a never-ending loop of the user uploading the original photo, triggering the compression and placing back in the same bucket, triggering compression again, etc.

Is there a way I can intercept this before it becomes a recursive call for image compression? Or is the only way to create a third bucket?

Answer (score 2):

A third bucket would probably be the best. If you really want to use the same bucket, just choose some criteria controlling whether the image in `photos` should be modified or not (perhaps image file size or something), then ensure that images that have been processed once fall below the threshold. The lambda will still run twice, but the second time it will examine the image and find it has already been processed and thus not process it again. To my knowledge there is no way to suppress the second run of the lambda.

Another option might be to filter based on [how the object is created](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#supported-notification-event-types). The following event types can be used in S3. Use one for what your users upload (maybe POST?) and the other for what your lambda does (maybe PUT?)

- s3:ObjectCreated:Put
- s3:ObjectCreated:Post
- s3:ObjectCreated:Copy
- s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload

Answer (score 0):

A third bucket would work, or essentially the same thing, rename the file with a prefix after compressing and then check for that prefix before reprocessing the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you name the outputs of your function in a predictable way, you can just filter any files that were created by your function at the start of the function.

However, as was mentioned previously, using a different bucket for the output would be simpler.